# Xpath not getting the max value

Tags: xml, xpath

So I'm stuck using Xpath 1.0 and I can't seem to get max working.... here's my Xpath query:

```
//m:REPORT_DATA[m:DATA_ITEM = 'LMP_PRC' and //m:INTERVAL_NUM[not(//INTERVAL_NUM > m:INTERVAL_NUM)]]/m:VALUE/text()
```

I am trying to get the find the value for the highest interval number with data_item=LMP_PRC   The only part that's not working is the "max" which comes after the "and".

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample XML and desired result.

Comment: Sample XML is a huge file:  Seen here:  http://pastebin.com/55f8XMi1   The desired result is the "value" for "LMP_PRC" during the highest (max) interval_num

Comment: Note: I cannot use max, due to java only having native xpath 1.0 support

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. I assume you are able to provide sample XML which reproduces your problem.

Comment: I included a pastebin link to the xml file above, it's huge.   I'm assuming that the max interval for LMP_PRC in the file linked there should be about ~240, and should have a value of around 30.

Comment: I will try to clarify. I'm asking for sample XML, e.g. `<a><b>1</b><b>3</b></a>`. I'd like to get result... and so on.

Comment: The actual xml I'm using is right here... I can make a sample of the data structure if you'd prefer... http://pastebin.com/55f8XMi1

Comment: You should reduce your `//` usage

Comment: @Damien.Bell, It would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this return the expected value? For the second sample, it returns 27.47472.

```
//m:REPORT_DATA[m:DATA_ITEM='LMP_PRC' and not(m:INTERVAL_NUM < //m:INTERVAL_NUM)]/m:VALUE/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subexpression

```
//m:INTERVAL_NUM[not(//INTERVAL_NUM > m:INTERVAL_NUM)]
```

is inside a predicate, which means you are only using its boolean value; it is true if this subexpression selects at least one node, which it always does, so the condition is redundant.

I can't help you correct the query without seeing more of your requirements. I would point out however that if your source document is "huge" then this is going to take "for ever", where "for ever" is a time proportional to "huge"-squared.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java then you are not stuck with XPath 1.0. XPath 2.0 support for Java has been available (primarily but not exclusively from Saxon) for many years. Rather than solving this problem with one hand tied behind your back, it's time to download the right tools for the job.